# Does Resilience4J keep retry method parameters in memory for the next retry method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

Using Resilience4j for fault tolerance. The question is, does retry method keep the parameter values in memory for the next retry?

If so it would create another problem, of accumulating pending retry data in memory.

Imagine I'm sending an email, parameters like from, to, subject, content, are sent to this notification service through rest api call. But this service is unavailable, so i put a retry on it for 100 times and the library keeps these email data to be sent on next retry. So my question is, since the library will keep that data in memory, if more users keep using that service which is unavailable, more data is kept in memory until they are sent.

I know lower retry time solves this. But isn't this a concern?

Comment: Accumulating why? Parameter values are stored on the stack.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- i provided more details